# Unity Animator - Idle state moves my character back to starting position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm trying to animate a spaceship barrel roll, and for some reason when the roll animation end, the ship goes back to the starting position. Attaching a GIF to display :

https://gfycat.com/glaringgrotesqueherring
https://gifyu.com/image/tQ8I

Here is how I set up the animator, as you can see there are no properites on the idle animation:
[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Is "Apply root motion" ticked on any of those animations in your diagram?

Comment: I dont have the apply root motion option on the animations themselves. I see it in the animator component of the main gameobject. And yes it is ticked there.